# MySQL UNION and ORDER - multiple select queries on single table

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to select max 250 rows from one table. First i want to select `ALL` rows that have column `locked='1'` and after that select `X` number of  rows that have column `locked = '0'` sorted by column `since` (timestamp).

X is 250 - num rows from firest query.

I tried this:

```
select * from (
select * from aktivni as a1 where locked = '1'
union
select * from aktivni as a2 where locked = '0'
) as tb1 limit 250
```

but with this I don't get correct values with second query (not ordered by `since`).

And if I do this:

```
select * from (
select * from aktivni as a1 where locked = '1'
union
select * from aktivni as a2 where locked = '0' ORDER BY since DESC
) as tb1 limit 250
```

than everything is ordered by `since` and I don't get `ALL` values that have column `locked` set to 1.

Is union right approach or can i do something else?

The workaround would be to write code in php to do that. First I would select all with:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE locked = '1'`

than I would count rows and with second query get remaining rows 
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE locked = '0' LIMIT (250 - num_rows_from_first_query)` but I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a `union` - you can just use a condition in your `order by` with `limit`:

```
select locked, since
from aktivni cross
order by locked = '1' desc, since desc
limit 250
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f497e/3)

Comment: nice answer @sgeddes, if you don't mind can you please explain what will do condition in `order by`?

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia -- the condition orders all results where `locked = 1` first, and then the remaining results by `since desc`.  In combination with `limit`, this can produce the desired results.

Comment: `select locked, since from aktivni order by locked asc, since desc imit 5` is there any difference between this query and your ans?